# atoi() produces incorrect value when applied to a large command line argument

Tags: c++, atoi, int64

I read in the value 300000000000 from command line and use atoi to convert it to int64_t however it outputs the wrong value.

```
int main(int argc, char * const argv[]){
  int64_t timeSlice = -1;

  if(argc == 4){
      timeSlice = atoi(argv[1])
      cout<<"timeslice: "<<timeSlice<<endl;

  }
}
```

I run my program on number `300000000000`

Expected out:
`timeSlice: 300000000000`
Actual output:
`timeslice: -647710720`
I even tried using stringstream and it would work, but when I passed timeslice to another function, the value in that function was still wrong

Comment: you need atol or atoll

Comment: `atoi` is a pretty simple tool. A blunt instrument.There's minimal error-checking, so it falls on you to make sure the input is good before you use it.

Comment: @Scheff, sorry didn't realize. I'll make sure to avoid doing that in the future

Answer (score 0):

Use [`strtoll`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/strtoll/) function:

```
timeSlice = strtoll(argv[1], nullptr, 10);
```

Comment: timeSlice = strtoll(argv[1], nullptr, 10); works but when I pass timeSlice as an argument to another function and print it out there it still gives me the same incorrect value ```-647710720```

Comment: How are you doing your printing?  Are you using %d or %ld or %lld?

Comment: @DenisShevchenko check `errno` and rather than passing in `nullptr` pass in a `char *` so you can see where the conversion stopped. [Here's some documentation to help you out.](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtol)

Comment: @user4581301, I updated my code and now it prints out a correct value in my main, but same incorrect value in foo. So it seems like it reads it in right, but passes wrong.

Comment: Duplicate I cannot.

Comment: @user4581301, make sure argc==4 when you run it.

Comment: I just changed `if(argc == 4)` to `if(argc == 2)`

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on whether you are using a 32 bit or 64 bit system and whether you are using Windows or Linux

atoi, atol, strtol and strtold will all return a 32-bit number on a 32-bit executable.

atoll, strtoll will return a 64 bit number on both 32 and 64-bit executables

atol, strtol, strtold will return a 32 bit number on a 64-bit Windows executable but a 64 bit number on a 64 bit Linux executable.

On 64-bit windows executable, long=int, 64-bit linux executable long=long long

Comment: I ssh into my school network which runs linux 64bit system.

Comment: Do you know if you are building a 32 or 64 bit executable?

Comment: It is a 64 bit executable